# Allow only ls on directories

Tags: permissions, ls

how can I set permissions to a folder so all users not in my group, can only do ls on it? I don't get the difference between - and r.

Comment: You want people to be able to list the contents of a directory, but not to e.g. `cd` into it, or access subdirectories?  Could you add a behaviour that you want to deny and one that you want to allow?

Answer (score 1):

The important flag is the "execute" flag on the directory, which on directories is actually a "traversable" flag. If it is not set, the directory cannot be used in a path. So: 1) you cannot CD to it, and 2) you cannot use the files in the directory.

Let's set up test ritg with a directory and a file

```
>>mkdir listonly
>>touch listonly/uselessfile
```

So far so good:

```
>>ls listonly/
uselessfile
```

Change the executable flag of the directory:

```
>>chmod -x listonly
```

You can no longer CD to it:

```
>>cd listonly
bash: cd: listonly: Permission denied
```

When you use `ls` you can see the files:

```
>>ls listonly/
uselessfile
```

However, in many cases `ls` is aliased to add some options that require looking at the metadata for each file (flags, timestamp, size...), which it cannot do since that requires using the directory in a path (for me that was `ls --color=auto'`) so you have to use plain `ls` otherwise you get a of the files but with unsightly errors:

```
>>ls listonly/
ls: cannot access 'listonly/uselessfile': Permission denied
uselessfile
```

Note that file explorers typically change their working directory to the target directory to list its contents, so this may not play well with GUI interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

Example:

```
#change current directory to /tmp/
vodka@vodka-PC:~$ cd /tmp/

#create my_folder directory in tmp
vodka@vodka-PC:/tmp$ mkdir my_folder

#chnage directory permissions to 775 
(all people can show dir content and make cd, 
but can not remove or create new files)
vodka@vodka-PC:/tmp$ chmod 775 my_folder/

#check permissions
vodka@vodka-PC:/tmp$ ls -ld my_folder
drwxrwxr-x 2 vodka vodka 4096 окт 20 11:26 my_folder

#create new test file
nano ./my_folder/test_file.txt

#chage file permission to 770 (only owner and member of groups can show file content and modify it)
vodka@vodka-PC:/tmp$ chmod 770 ./my_folder/test_file.txt

#test it. Switch to postgres user and show dir content. We see files in directory
vodka@vodka-PC:/tmp$ sudo su - postgres
postgres@vodka-PC:~$ ls -l /tmp/my_folder/
-rwxrwx--- 1 vodka vodka 4 окт 20 11:27 test_file.txt
#try to show file content, remove or create new files in dir
cat: /tmp/my_folder/test_file.txt: Permission denied
postgres@vodka-PC:~$ >/tmp/my_folder/test_file_2.txt
-bash: /tmp/my_folder/test_file_2.txt: Permission denied
postgres@vodka-PC:~$ rm /tmp/my_folder/test_file.txt
rm: remove write-protected regular file '/tmp/my_folder/test_file.txt'? y
rm: cannot remove '/tmp/my_folder/test_file.txt': Permission denied
```

So, other users can only show list of files.